# How do I see/use the data sent by a http POST?

Tags: php, android

I have been searching through SO for the last few days and have found many Q/A regarding my problem but have not been about to solve it. I am trying to make an Android app that sends 4 (maybe 5) pieces of data to a php script on my webserver. I believe this code does that:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php");

            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "name"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var1", "var1"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var2", "var2"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("var3", "var3"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            }
```

My question is this: Hows does this data get sent? I thought it would be in this format
http://www.mydomain.com/myscript.php?name=name&var1=var1&var2=var2&var3=var3

So I thought this myscript.php would work:

```
    <?php
    $name = $_GET['name'];

    $filename = "newfile.php";
    $newfile = fopen($filename, 'w+');
    fwrite($newfile, $name);
    fclose($newfile);
    ?>
```

I have tried a lot of various ways, like $name = file_get_contents('php://input') to try and see what is being received but no luck.

I am new to android and php so I presume I am missing something quite obvious, since all the other Q/A on SO seem to skip the 'how to retrieve and use the data being sent'. All I need the php script to do is grab the 4 variables and write a new file as above with them in it.

I would also like to know how to get a response back to the app simply saying the data has been received. I presume that is handled by the variable 'response' but am not able to test that yet.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data is sent via POST method, not GET. So, all data is in **`$_POST`**.

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];

  $filename = "newfile.php";
  $newfile = fopen($filename, 'w+');
  fwrite($newfile, $name);
  fclose($newfile);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used $_POST instead and it works with an 'echo' but for some reason it won't create a new file called newfile.php. Yet I have other php files in same directory using the 'same' code and they will happily create the file if it does not exist. If the file is there and is writable it works, but otherwise returns an error. Any ideas for that?

Comment: Have you got write permission on that folder? _returns an error_, what error?

Comment: Thank-you. By making the permissions on the whole folder 'writable' it is now working. Strange though, as before it was not, yet another php script was able to fopen and create a file if it did not exists.

Comment: Also, the error was - unable to open stream or something like that with regards to the fopen command

Comment: If you solved setting write permission, file permission was the problem. I can't say you if other script are different from your (for example, if they are run by another user account who is able to create file in there) or if the permission flags have changed over time. Btw, I'm glad I helped you.

Comment: Thank you, yes you have solved my original question. I am now having issues with writing to and/or creating my filename.php. The other way I am doing it is via an email and/or txt being piped to a different php script. This script could create the filename.php before making the folder writable. Now I have a problem where once the file does exists, which ever method did NOT create it cannot open/write to it.

Comment: Ok, so if I solved the problem on you question, accept my answer, thank you. And then, if you now have a new different problem, just write another question. Stack Overflow works this way, it is not a forum but a question / answer community :) I'm glad I helped you.